# Как запустить "Беспроводное сетевое соединение 3" через командную строку

Tags: сеть, cmd

Есть вот такое [Беспроводное сетевое соединение 3](http://cs5548.vkontakte.ru/u23671697/92461701/z_665167c2.jpg), оно выключено.
Подскажите как его включить по средством командной строки (консоли)?
И как можно разрешить [общий доступ к подключению к интернету](http://cs5548.vkontakte.ru/u23671697/92461701/x_3550c13d.jpg) также через командную строку (консоль)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ОС семейства Linux можно, в Windows утилитой "cmd.exe" скорее всего нет, только через powershell.
Включаем сетевой адаптер:

```
$adaptor = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*Беспроводное сетевое соединение 3*"}
$adaptor.Enable()
```

Как перевести сетевуху в режим раздачи средствами powershell я хз.

*P.S.: Запустить Windows PowerShell: Кнопочка Start -> Programs -> Accessories -> папка Windows PowerShell -> собственно сам Windows PowerShell*

Comment: Спасибо. Я к сожалению не на столько прошарен что в консоли что в powershell. Поясни пожалуйста.

Comment: Указанный в ответе код ищет сетевой адатер с указанным именем и включает его. Я не педагог, научить не смогу. Особенно если человек не знаком с обычной консолькой. Можете тут(http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc281945.aspx) почитать.